# How can I get data from a URL link?

Tags: java

My goal is to be able to prompt the user for a URL, and be able to read the URL for data, then use that data and turn it into vertices. This is the [URL](https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/test/GraphSample1.txt)

All the other guides out there have only printed the URL data, but I don't know what to do at all. This is all I have:

```
String urlString = "https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/test/GraphSample1.txt";

// create the url
URL url = new URL(urlString);

// open the url stream, wrap it an a few "readers"
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

// write the output to stdout
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read the data from given URL?

Comment: If you want to read the contents of the URL , you can use InputStreamReader for the same.